# windows Azure migration error

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am following a tutorial of using azure with asp.net with an sql database, and having a hard time trying to get past an error I am receiving. the tutorial I am following is - "http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/#aspnetwindowsazureinfo"

in the package manager console i have typed in " enable-migrations -ContextTypeName ToDoListApp.Models.ToDoDb" and that worked correctly, as shown below with my output.

```
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project ToDoListApp.
```

I then typed in "add-migration Initial" and I have received this error..

"Cannot scaffold the next migration because the target database was created with a version of Code First earlier than EF 4.3 and does not contain the migrations history table. To start using migrations against this database, ensure the current model is compatible with the target database and execute the migrations Update process. (In Visual Studio you can use the Update-Database command from Package Manager Console to execute the migrations Update process)."

i also used the command "-Verbose" - and found out the error is in the target database.

```
Using StartUp project 'ToDoListApp'.
Using NuGet project 'ToDoListApp'.
Target database is: 'ToDoListApp.Models.ToDoDb' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
```

- note :* i have set up a website on azure, along with the sql database and linked it to this project by publishing.

I have typed the error into Google, some say that " Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges" can fix it, from

"http://www.woohoo.uk.com/Blog/updating-entity-framework-4-1-with-code-first-migrations"

and others say to just update-database in the package manager console, which neither seem to work, I am following a tutorial provided from Microsoft, and along the way I received this problem.

any help to resolve this situation would be grateful, im using visual studio 2012, c# asp.net mv3 framework 4.5.

in my web.config file, i also have inputted the code

```
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <contexts>
      <context type="ToDoListApp.Models.ToDoDb, ToDoListApp">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion">
        <parameters>
          <parameter value="ToDoDb_DatabasePublish"/>
        </parameters>
        </databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
```

i typed in "Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges"

and the error outputted was ..

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to set database initializer of type                 'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion' for DbContext type 'ToDoListApp.Models.ToDoDb, ToDoListApp' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,  Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.DatabaseInitializerElement.GetInitializerType()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.InternalApplyInitializers(Boolean force)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.InternalApplyInitializers(Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.Exists[TContext](HistoryContextBase`1 context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetPendingMigrations(IEnumerable`1 localMigrations)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.GetPendingMigrations()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetPendingMigrationsRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Failed to set database initializer of type 'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion' for DbContext type 'ToDoListApp.Models.ToDoDb, ToDoListApp' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed -

just required for me to login at sql server object explorer and delete the EdmMetadata under tables, and input my connection string in web.config, heres an example if anyone ever does read this and had the same problem..

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=tcp:* insert server name*.database.windows.net,1433;Database=* insert database name *;User ID=*insert username *@* insert server name*;Password={*insert password here *};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"  />
```